# How to use dynamic resource URL in lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-sam

I have created a SQS from AWS SAM template.yaml which will return me the SQS path which is required by a lambda function to send message to. Now since the SQS path will be generated during the time of CFT stack creation, how can I use it beforehand or is there a way to use the dynamic SQS path ?

Not able to figure out please help.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you added a minimal code example to your question.

Comment: You pass the path / queue name as an environment variable to the lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, adding more details will help in getting better answers. Nevertheless, assuming that you are creating an SQS using the below template,

```
  myQueueLogicalId:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties: 
      QueueName: myQueue
      VisibilityTimeout: 4200
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
```

you can get the queue name (or if you want the full url or ARN change the attribute as given in the sqs cloudformation [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sqs-queue.html#aws-resource-sqs-queue-return-values-fn--getatt)) to your lambda function by passing it in the environment variable as below:

```
  myFunctionLogicalId:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Environment:
        Variables:
          MY_SQS: !GetAtt 
                      - myQueueLogicalId
                      - QueueName
      FunctionName: myFunction
      Handler: src/handlers/handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Timeout: 650
      MemorySize: 4096
```

This parameter can be retrieved in your code as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-retrieve).